# What is the difference between SQL Mapping and an ORM?

Tags: orm

I cannot find the difference between to two in my search on SO.  Can someone explain the difference to me?  I feel pretty confident on my understanding of an ORM.  But I do not know what SQL Mapping is, and therefore how it is different from an ORM.

I am using Java if it matters.
I control all of the database.

Is there an example of a small understandable SQL Mapper I could look at?

EDIT:  I really do not want to embed SQL in my code.  That's the devil.

Comment: The internet doesn't know either.  Can you tell us more about where you've seen the term used and defined?

Comment: Are you referring to mapping SQL query results vs. creating SQL queries via in language queries + mapping the results?